# how can I assign the value of keyword when I click the button

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

For example, in a calculator, there are 9 integers on the phone screen and else just like + - / * .... maybe something else. But I want to ask you one question. How can I append the value of keyword of the button to the display. Our developer created the button as text "5". When the user clicks that button, I want to display the 5 value in the edittext without clicking the number 5 value in the built-in keyboard in Android. Can anyone explain how to do this please?

"Keyword" means number 1 - 9 on the keyboard. Normally, when we create the `EditText`, we can easily input the keyword in `EditText` by using built-in keyboard. But I don't like it .

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure that I understand correctly, but are you looking to create an alternative to the built-in Android keyboard? Anyways, you are more likely to get an answer to your question if you can also provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) illustrating your problem, of course to the extent it is possible.

Comment: @andybega ... thank you for your suggestion. I give you a simply example. I want to set the value 7 in the edittext when user click the button that I typed as num 7 on display. you see? If you click the button, the edittext must show the value that already assigned. On display, there is button "5", when user click that button, I want to set the value in Edittext as 5 ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a `TextView` instead of `EditText` to display the numbers. But if you insist, it's also fine. If you look at the docs, you will see there is a `setText` method in `TextView` class. And because `EditText` extends `TextView`, it will have that as well.

You can use the `setText` method to set the text of the text view and use `getText` to get it. That is very simple. In a calculator app, you want to append (which means add something at the end of a string) the number to the existing text, right? So let me show you how to do this.

You can use this code to append "5" to the text view.

```
String originalText = yourTextView.getText ().toString();
yourTextView.setText (originalText + "5");
```

Just in case you don't know how to get the `TextView`:

```
yourTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.youtTextViewsId);
```

Comment: thanks sweeper, you don't understand what i mean. but I give you example. In calculator app, there is button 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc. ok...  when the customer click the 1 button, the value of 1 will show the edittext. when the customer click the 2, the value of 2 will show in edtitext. when click 3, value 3 will show in edittext... I want do like that... thanks you... but I dont' know this method...

Comment: Then you just use the `setText` method to set teh text to 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc. @AungThuYa